# In Store Pickup delivery Method is not working

Tags: magento2

I Upgrade the Magento Version from 2.3 to 2.4. I integrate the "In store Pickup" Delivery Method.
But this is not work .I follow the all steps Given in "https://store.magenest.com/blog/magento-in-store-pickup/"

Please Guys Let me know if anyone have idea what is the solution.